# How to get an idea to use ArcGIS tools in toolbox?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, arctoolbox

I want to see the definition of any tool in ArcGIS tool box and How to enable to see the procedure to use them and option to edit the tool?

Comment: Are you looking for a description of what the tool does? You can just right click the tool and select 'Item Description'.

Comment: i'm looking for parameters settings....

Comment: Each tool has a corresponding page in the help files that shows all the parameters, such as this http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Append/001700000050000000/

Comment: What I posted gives the data type of the parameter. Optional parameters are shown in {brackets}. Input/Output should be easy to determine if you open the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of editing existing tool you can create your own tools using python script with your additional functionality and you can find tool tip by right clicking any tool and choose help option to find the tool reference to pass the parameters on it.

Answer (score 6):

Every GUI-based tool has a "Tool Help" button on the bottom right.  There you will find all of the parameter information.  Alternatively, simply clicking on an input area will show necessary information about the parameters.

ESRI has one of the best [support sites around](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/).  Googling, for example, arcpy Dissolve will bring you directly to the specific support page.

If you are looking for tool source code, some of the tools are written as script tools in which case you can access the source code (see attached image).  You can access these scripts directly too: C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\Scripts.  Other source code such as "Clip" are not accessible, which is one of the reasons why people really like the open-source movement.

[image]